# Failed to publish message to Message Hub

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message, message-hub

```
// Asynchronous response from Message Hub / Kafka.
kafkaProducer.send(record,
new Callback() {
   public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata m, Exception e) {
       if(e != null) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       } else { 
    log.debug(" **** Message sent, offset: " + m.offset() + 
    " @ partition " + m.partition());
    log.debug(" <<<< " +
    " document_id " + key +
    " @ " + account.getActivityId());
    }
   }
});
```

When trying to publish message to Message Hub using above codes, we always get the following errors.

> 2016-06-21 18:38:22-[INFO]
>   com.ibm.cloudant.streaming.messageHub.Client.send(476):  >>>> sending 
>   document_id julia30 @ my_database
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[DEBUG] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(623):
>   Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[DEBUG] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(487):
>   Initiating connection to node -1 at
>   kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093.
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[DEBUG] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(105):
>   Creating SaslClient:
>   client=multiuser-adapter@multiuser.messagehub.ibm.com;service=kafka;serviceHostname=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net;mechs=[GSSAPI]
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[DEBUG] com.ibm.cloudant.streaming.messageHub.AccountManager.(53):
>   process id: 15825
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[INFO] org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(92):
>   Failed to create channel due to 
>       org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:96)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:89)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:162)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:489)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$400(NetworkClient.java:47)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:624)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:543)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:254)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create SaslClient
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:112)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:94)
>       ... 10 more
>       Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: PLAIN: authorization ID and password must be specified
>       at com.sun.security.sasl.PlainClient.(PlainClient.java:58)
>       at com.sun.security.sasl.ClientFactoryImpl.createSaslClient(ClientFactoryImpl.java:97)
>       at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384)
>       at com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(MessageHubSaslClientFactory.java:77)
>       at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:107)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:102)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:102)
>       ... 11 more
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[ERROR] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(130): Uncaught
>   error in kafka producer I/O thread: 
>       org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure
>   SaslClientAuthenticator
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:93)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:162)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:489)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$400(NetworkClient.java:47)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:624)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:543)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:254)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:96)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:89)
>       ... 9 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create SaslClient
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:112)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.configure(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:94)
>       ... 10 more
>       Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: PLAIN: authorization ID and password must be specified
>       at com.sun.security.sasl.PlainClient.(PlainClient.java:58)
>       at com.sun.security.sasl.ClientFactoryImpl.createSaslClient(ClientFactoryImpl.java:97)
>       at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384)
>       at com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubSaslClientFactory.createSaslClient(MessageHubSaslClientFactory.java:77)
>       at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:384)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:107)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator$1.run(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:102)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.createSaslClient(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:102)
>       ... 11 more
>       2016-06-21 18:38:22-[ERROR] org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(130): Uncaught
>   error in kafka producer I/O thread: 
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:268)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:256)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:128)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The setting for producer looks like:

```

```
 compression.type = none
 metric.reporters = []
 metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
 metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
 reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
 bootstrap.servers = [kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093]
 retry.backoff.ms = 100
 sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
 buffer.memory = 33554432
 timeout.ms = 30000
 key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
 sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
 ssl.keystore.type = JKS
 ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
 block.on.buffer.full = false
 ssl.key.password = null
 max.block.ms = 60000
 sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
 connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
 ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
 max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
 metrics.num.samples = 2
 client.id = kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net%3A9093_8qp87X32V6PK5epv.1
 ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
 ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
 request.timeout.ms = 30000
 ssl.provider = null
 ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
 acks = -1
 batch.size = 16384
 ssl.keystore.location = null
 receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
 ssl.cipher.suites = null
 ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 security.protocol = SASL_SSL
 retries = 1
 max.request.size = 1048576
 value.serializer = class  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
 ssl.truststore.location = /Users/jiangph/tools/liberty/usr/shared/resources/keystore.jks
 ssl.keystore.password = null
 ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
 metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
 send.buffer.bytes = 131072
 linger.ms = 0
```

```

Using above settings, there is no problem to create topic using Message Hub rest API. The problem happens when trying to publish message.

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

the MessageHub REST client API authenticates in a different way from java Kafka client.

I see that there is an authentication error in your log:
 `javax.security.sasl.SaslException: PLAIN: authorization ID and password must be specified at com.sun.security.sasl.PlainClient.`

To configure a java client for MessageHub SASL authentication, 
please see the java examples at :

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples/tree/master/java/message-hub-kafka-ssl

Note that your producer properties should include these:

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples/blob/master/java/message-hub-kafka-ssl/resources/producer.properties

And your jaas.conf file should look like

`KafkaClient {
      com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubLoginModule required
      serviceName="kafka"
      username="your-username"
      password="your-password";
    };`

and that you must have the MessageHub login jar in your classpath.

HTH,
Edo

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was completely unrelated to authentication and had to do with key/value serialization. Changing from

```
    props.setProperty("key.serializer", 
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.setProperty("value.serializer", 
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
```

to

```
    props.setProperty("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    props.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
```

resolved the javax.security.sasl.SaslException

Strangely enough, once you have used ByteArraySerialization successfully, you can even switch back to StringSerialization and things will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

I can run both consumer or producer samples with the StringSerializer and have never had a need to switch. 
The serializer does not apply to SASL authentication.